# iOS: keep task running when in sleep mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, sleep

I'm trying to develop a little app in order to learn coding for iOS. The app needs to check the battery level every minute and accordingly send an HTTP request. This works when the app is awake.

How can I make it run when the device is put in sleep mode?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't, or at least shouldn't.
Apple doesn't allow apps to run in the background for extended periods of time with a few exceptions like navigation apps, VoIP apps and a few others (a full list can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)).
I recommend that you read about `UIBackgroundModes` and the app lifecycle in the link I attached.

Happy coding!

Comment: Are you sure? I do music apps manage to keep running music in the background? The only thing I need to do is periodically compare two values, that shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Music apps are one of the exceptions. You can read about it in the link I attached. If your app is of a type listed in those exceptions then you might be able to achieve what you set out to do, possibly with some limitations